# Thread contention when allocating memory

Tags: c#, multithreading, memory-management

In C#, I run a toy code that creates many small objects (which I know should ideally be avoided - I just want to study the problem). For the same total amount of objects created, one thread runs faster than one thread per processor (Parallel.For).

The atomic action consists in creating a list (actually an array) containing 20k small objects (here long[4] for simplicity):

```
private static void CreateList()
{
    long[][] list = new long[20000][];
    for (var i = 0; i < 20000; i++)
        list[i] = new long[4];
}
```

If I create 1000 lists in a single thread it runs in 1.5s. If I create 1000 lists with several threads (each responsible for a subset of the 1000 lists), It runs in 2s.

The behaviour is essentially the same when:

- using classical small objects instead of long[4]
- using a real List instead of an array
- using different number of objects

**Could you explain why? Is there a "lock" in the memory manager. Is it related to garbage collection?**

Details of the code:

```
public static void Main()
{
    Benchmark(1000, CreateList);
}    

private static void Benchmark(int repeat, Action action)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Single thread");
    Benchmark(delegate ()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < repeat; i++)
            action();
    });
    Console.WriteLine("Multi thread");
    Benchmark(delegate ()
    {
        Parallel.For(0, repeat, i => action());
    });
}

private static void Benchmark(Action action)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        action();
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Time : " + sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course Memory Management is single threaded by nature. Both the allocation and collection. Otherwise you would run into race condition when trying to allocate the same pieces of memory!

Comment: Other than what has been said above, and not sure if it is also another thing you are asking, just because you spawn multiple threads it does not necessarily mean it will run faster. Creating threads has an overhead within itself, so for very short tasks running things in parallel does not always result in a smaller execution time.

Comment: I concur with what npinti said too. I like to say "Multithreading has to pick it's problems carefully". Otherwise you end up with code that is more complex (prone to errors), uses more memory and is **slower** then a single thread. Parallel Slowdown is a thing (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_slowdown). As is problems that can not be multithreaded at all. Just try to Multithreading the Fibbonacci Sequence so that each number is created by a seperate Thread.

Comment: @npitni; The threads do not run short tasks here. There is not overhead. Replace memory allocation by maths and you will you see it.

Comment: @BenoitSanchez: If I replace a Memory Bound Operation with a CPU bound one, it is not even similar code anymore.

Comment: What you want to do is possible, if you give each thread it's own slice of memory to manually manage. What I consider one of the oldest forms of Multitasking, is just starting multiple instance of the same (sub)programm. The other way would be to allocate a chunk of memory, then implement your own thread level Memory Management.

Comment: @Christopher. I see what you mean sure. It's just that the overhead seems to be surprisingly high. Basically Microsoft says allocation is only moving a pointer forward (like Interlocked.Add): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973837.aspx#dotnetgcbasics_topic3. I find a bit slow to move a pointer forward... I wonder how collection is related to this contention.

Comment: @BenoitSanchez Just for completeness, you may want to try to run your code with server GC enabled and see the results. In server GC, there is a managed heap per core, which allows to do allocations in parallel

Comment: There is no real overhead. It simply **can not** work in paralell. There is a single GC instance. And it **has** to use locking and similar mutex approaches. Otherwise it might end up assigning the native pointer 0011 to two threads by accident. But as Kevin pointed out, there are alternative GC modes like the Server one, wich move some part of hte allocation to a Thread Level thing.

Comment: @Kevin. I did it and it changes the picture completely (single thread 0.5s, multi-thread: 0.4s): . Maybe you could turn it into an answer if you want.

Comment: @BenoitSanchez I just provided a way to test Christopher's theory. He's the one who provided most of the answer

Comment: I don't know enough about C# memory allocation and usage patterns but this strongly reminds me of False Sharing problems where cache coherance causes a slowdown because a change in the cache of 1 processesing core causes the cache of another to update even though their data don't needs to be kept coherent.

Comment: @R Betchel. I don't think it's false sharing here. Because there is no write except in the "list" that is large enough to avoid false sharing. Actually false sharing was my first idea when trying to understand this kind of problem (actually I'm studying why a certain open-source lib has poor perf).

Comment: @BenoitSanchez There's no false sharing for the assignation (`list[i] = `), but there could be false sharing for the allocation (`new long[4]`) since they're allocated on the same memory segment (and probably continuously)

Comment: Tested with a bigger array size (`list[i] = new long[514];`) but no change, so I don't think it's false sharing after all (unless cache lines are much bigger than I expect)

Comment: I thought of this after writing my comment :-). Actually false sharing is rare with many small objects because the probability two threads are processing two objects in the same (cache) block is small. Well here it's not that clear... since they only write on objects recently created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though it is normal the memory manager uses some kind of semaphore, multi-threaded apps with many memory allocations work very bad with the default C# garbage collector. With the proper garbage collector, things are MUCH better.

You should:

- enable server GC
- (possibly) disable concurrent GC

Server GC will allow a better degree of parallelization between threads since memory allocation is partially independent. In this kind of situation, the performance can change radically on machines with several cores.

For short, add this to the config file of your project:

```
  <runtime>
    <gcServer enabled="true"/>
    <gcConcurrent enabled="false" />
  </runtime>
```

You can read details about server and workstation GC in [Fundamentals of Garbage Collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals#workstation_and_server_garbage_collection).