# I have no idea why the multi-thread coding cannot reduce the computing time in my code

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, locking, performance-testing

I am trying to reduce the computing time using the multi-thread technique. My problem is to calculate the score of independent items. For example, I have 10 items and need to get the score for each item. I can use the single thread ten times serially for getting the score or the multi-thread parallelly.

In my code, the computing time was just reduced about average 7% when I used a multi-thread code. I expected multi-thread code would reduce it over about 50%.

I also changed the power plan (Control Panel > Hardware and Sound > Power Options) from Balanced to High performance for it.

I solved the same problem using four options.

1. Single Thread and Balanced Option : 11min
2. Multi Thread and Balanced Option : 10min 40Sec (20sec decreased)
3. Single Thread and High Performance : 10 min
4. Multi Thread and High Performance : 10min 10sec.(10sec increased)

My questions are

1. What is wrong in my code as below?
2. Why does the computing time of multi-thread code increase compared to that of single-thread code when the power option sets the high performance (3 and 4 case as above)
3. How many core do I need for improving computing time? the more is the better??

I am a beginner in the multi-thread world in C#. Please guide me to go right.
Thank you for your kind answer in advance.

I made a simple example for explaining our code structure. The code creates 10000 items and gets the score of them. Also we use the "lock" for parallel computing of List structure.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SampleCode
{
    class Program
    {       
        static List<Item> Storage = new List<Item>();
        static object key = new object();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Item> items = CreateItems(10000);
            int maxDegreeOfParallelism = 4;

            Parallel.ForEach(items, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = maxDegreeOfParallelism },
                (item) => Evaluate(item));                
        }

        public static void Evaluate(Item item)
        {
            item.Score = 0;

            item.Score += GetScore1(item);
            item.Score += GetScore2(item);            
        }

        public static double GetScore1(Item item)
        {
            return item.UnitQty * 100;
        }
        public static double GetScore2(Item item)
        {
            lock (key)
            {
                if (item.UnitQty % 2 == 0)
                    Storage.Add(item);
                else if (Storage.Count > 0)
                    Storage.RemoveAt(Storage.Count - 1);

                return item.UnitQty * Storage.Count;
            }
        }
        
        public static List<Item> CreateItems(int count)
        {
            List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
            for(int i=0; i<count; i++)
            {
                items.Add(CreateItem(i));
            }

            return items;
        }
        public static Item CreateItem(int index)
        {
            Item item = new Item();

            item.UnitQty = index % 25 + 1;
            return item;
        }

        internal class Item
        {
            public double Score;
            public int UnitQty;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The computationally expensive part is probably within the `lock` statement where all threads have to wait on each other, so you're not seeing much benefit from extra threads.

Comment: Welcome! Imagine having one person adding users to a single list. That takes a certain amount of time. Now imagine having 100 guys adding the same users to the same, single list again. You'll have to make sure that you synchronize that action, because only one can use the list at a time. That's what happens with your lock statement, there's no speed improvement. Parallelism is only useful if the actual task of calculating/creating the user to be added takes a long time.

Comment: I struggle to see how the code within `GetScore2` can ever be deterministic even with the `lock` because it removes items from `Storage` dependent on the data. This means the order that the items are processed matters and with multiple threads racing for the lock, that is not predictable. What is the desired outcome of this code?

Comment: Thank you for your attention. It is a simplified code to explain my code. The original code just get the deterministic scores of items depending on the item's priority, location, degree of delay and so on.

Comment: If you can remove the call to Storage.RemoveAt it should be trivial to rewrite this with PLinq and a select, which would remove the contention around that lock. But as it stands its a bit hard to give advise because the desired outcome is unclear.

Comment: @Jason My desired outcome is very simple. We assume  item_1 has priroity_score =2, location_score = 3, delay_score =2;   item_2  has priroity_score =4, location_score = 3, delay_score =1;   item_3 has  priroity_score = 5, location_score = 2, delay_score =3 and priority_weight = 30, location_weight = 40, delay_weight = 50. The scores of items are item_1 = 2*30 + 3*40 + 2*50 = 280, item_2 = 4 *30 + 3*40+ 1*50 = 290, item_3 = 5 * 30 + 2 * 40 + 3 * 50 = 380. I am sorry that I gave a little confused code for explaining my code.

Answer (score 0):

You have 4 items doing a tiny calculation then waiting in line to be able to add or remove a result from your container.

Parallelism is better used for compute heavy tasks, right now I would estimate the start up/stop overhead is almost equal to the computation work its doing. Add locking into the equation and more of the time savings being eaten into.

Answer (score 0):

Based off of your comment:

> We assume item_1 has priroity_score =2, location_score = 3, delay_score =2; item_2 has priroity_score =4, location_score = 3, delay_score =1; item_3 has priroity_score = 5, location_score = 2, delay_score =3 and priority_weight = 30, location_weight = 40, delay_weight = 50. The scores of items are item_1 = 2*30 + 3*40 + 2*50 = 280, item_2 = 4 *30 + 3*40+ 1*50 = 290, item_3 = 5 * 30 + 2 * 40 + 3 * 50 = 380

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace SampleCode
{

    /*
     * We assume 
     * item_1 has priroity_score =2, location_score = 3, delay_score =2; 
     * item_2 has priroity_score =4, location_score = 3, delay_score =1; 
     * item_3 has priroity_score = 5, location_score = 2, delay_score =3 
     * 
     * and priority_weight = 30, location_weight = 40, delay_weight = 50. 
     * The scores of items are item_1 = 2*30 + 3*40 + 2*50 = 280, item_2 = 4 *30 + 3*40+ 1*50 = 290, item_3 = 5 * 30 + 2 * 40 + 3 * 50 = 38
     * */
    class Program
    {
        static List<Item> Storage = new List<Item>();
        static object key = new object();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var range = Enumerable.Range(0, 10000);

            var maxDegreeOfParallelism = 4;

            var priorityWeight = 30;
            var locationWeight = 40;
            var delayWeight = 50;


            var items = range
                .AsParallel()
                .WithDegreeOfParallelism(maxDegreeOfParallelism)
                .Select(i =>
                {
                    var item = new Item { PriorityScore = i + 2, LocationScore = i + 3, DelayScore = i + 2 };
                    item.Score = Evaluate(item, priorityWeight, locationWeight, delayWeight);
                    return item;
                });

            Storage.AddRange(items);
        }

        private static double Evaluate(Item item, int priorityWeight, int locationWeight, int delayWeight)
        {
            return item.PriorityScore * priorityWeight + item.LocationScore * locationWeight + item.DelayScore * delayWeight;
        }

        internal class Item
        {
            public double Score;
            public double PriorityScore;
            public double LocationScore;
            public double DelayScore;
        }
    }
}
```

But even here, running with PLinq takes ~30ms in debug where removing multithreading will take ~2ms because of the threading overhead vs the light weight operations you are performing. Also note that memory is a shared resource and is not CPU bound, so heap allocations will present an area of contention.  ([Thread contention when allocating memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50291375/thread-contention-when-allocating-memory))
In your example code the contention is created by the lock in `GetScore2`.

If your final code has more complex operations or if you are processing a very large number of inputs. As long as you avoid locking, using plinq might give you better improvements than shown here.

You can also use Parallel.ForEach if you have pre-allocated values:

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SampleCode
{

    /*
     * We assume 
     * item_1 has priroity_score =2, location_score = 3, delay_score =2; 
     * item_2 has priroity_score =4, location_score = 3, delay_score =1; 
     * item_3 has priroity_score = 5, location_score = 2, delay_score =3 
     * 
     * and priority_weight = 30, location_weight = 40, delay_weight = 50. 
     * The scores of items are item_1 = 2*30 + 3*40 + 2*50 = 280, item_2 = 4 *30 + 3*40+ 1*50 = 290, item_3 = 5 * 30 + 2 * 40 + 3 * 50 = 38
     * */
    class Program
    {
        static List<Item> Storage = new List<Item>();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //     Bumped n to see results  vvvvvvvv
            var range = Enumerable.Range(0, 10000000);

            var maxDegreeOfParallelism = 4;

            var priorityWeight = 30;
            var locationWeight = 40;
            var delayWeight = 50;

            var items = range
                .Select(i => new Item { PriorityScore = i + 2, LocationScore = i + 3, DelayScore = i + 2 })
                .ToList();

            Parallel.ForEach(items, 
                new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = maxDegreeOfParallelism }, 
                i => i.Score = Evaluate(i, priorityWeight, locationWeight, delayWeight));
            //~43ms

            foreach(var i in items)
            {
                i.Score = Evaluate(i, priorityWeight, locationWeight, delayWeight);
            }
            //~99ms

            Storage.AddRange(items);
        }

        private static double Evaluate(Item item, int priorityWeight, int locationWeight, int delayWeight)
        {
            return item.PriorityScore * priorityWeight + item.LocationScore * locationWeight + item.DelayScore * delayWeight;
        }

        internal class Item
        {
            public double Score;
            public double PriorityScore;
            public double LocationScore;
            public double DelayScore;
        }
    }
}
```

As always with concurrency, there are tradeoffs and you will need to benchmark for your specific needs.

Answer (score -1):

Multithreading can take notably significant time to switch between thread contexts, so it is not obliged to give some speed-up. Sometimes everything happens the other way around.